# Efficiently test if an Element will be in a jQuery collection

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, jquery-selectors

Given a jQuery collection like this `$(selector,containerElement)`, is it possible to test if a given Element will be part of that collection without constructing the collection at all.

That is, without doing this: `$(selector,containerElement).is(someElement)`, which will construct a jQuery object with all the matched elements inside and then check if one of those elements  is `someElement`.

Is there a more efficient way of doing it?

PS: Keep in mid that jQuery supports additional selector syntax like `:has()`, `:lt()`, `:first` and relative selectors like `> tagName`, `+ tagName`.

Comment: jQuery is itself very efficient. Why would you need to do this?

Comment: @gforce301, the exhaustive method is not fast enough when you need to do it with high frequency, like inside a `setInterval` callback or in response to a move event.

Comment: Now 3-4 users spent their time on something that could been avoided if you would have made a simple sample taking all oddities into account.

Comment: @LGSon I assumed it was common knowledge that jQuery supports more selectors that the native API. I edited the question to make that clear.

Comment: @GetFree It is common knowledge but these selectors may or may not have been useful in your case. Now we know they are.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up implementing my own custom solution for this.
The following function does the trick.

```
function jQueryMatch(selector, container, element){
    let attrName = '_dummy_876278983232' ;
    let attrValue = (''+Math.random()).slice(2) ;
    $(container).attr(attrName,attrValue) ;
    selector = selector.replace(/(,|^)(\s*[>~+])/g,`$1 [${attrName}=${attrValue}]$2`) ;
    return $(element).is(selector) ;
}
```

`jQueryMatch(selector, container, element)` is equivalent to `$(selector, container).is(element)`.

I measured `jQueryMatch` to be between 3 and 10 times faster depending on the complexity of the selector. On bigger DOM trees, the difference will be even greater.

The function is super simple so it's easy to figure out what it does.

Answer (score 0):

$.contains(containerElement, someElement);

Comment: `.contains()` only checks if the element is a descendant. The css selector may be more complex.

Comment: Good point, you could also try using .filter() and test the desired equivalency to your standards.

Answer (score 0):

If performance is an issue, you could use vanilla JS for this, such as:

```
[...yourContainer.querySelectorAll('yourSelector')].includes(elementToTest)
```

**Sample**:

```js
let container = document.querySelector('[data-container');
let insideElement = container.querySelector('[data-inside-element]');
let outsideElement = container.querySelector('[data-outside-element]');

console.log([...container.querySelectorAll('[data-inside-element]')].includes(insideElement));
console.log([...container.querySelectorAll('[data-inside-element]')].includes(outsideElement));
```

```html
<div data-container>
  <p data-inside-element>element1</p>
  <p data-inside-element>element2</p>
  <p data-inside-element>element3</p>
</div>

<p data-outside-element>outside element</p>
```

Comment: The native DOM API won't work because jQuery supports additional selector syntax like `$('> div',container)` or `$('+ div',container)` or `$('~ div',container)` among others.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on Brian Reynolds's answer:

```
$.contains(containerElement, someElement) && someElement.is(selector)
```

However, this won't work if `selector` starts with operators like `>`, `+`, or `~` that require it to be in a specific position relative to `containerElement`, since we've separated those variables.

Comment: That wont work for relative selectors like `$('> div',container)` or `$('+ div',container)` or `$('~ div',container)`